# Can I use or access the San Francisco font that comes with El Capitan?

Tags: macos, font

The new font *San Francisco*, introduced in El Capitan throughout OS X's Finder and contextual menus, is a beautiful font and proves that once again, Apple is on top of their game when it comes to defining the standards of UI and typography.

[image]

But when I try to find *San Francisco* in TextEdit or Keynote, it's not there.

[image]

The apps I use, whether Apple apps (Pages, Numbers, TextEdit...) or third-party apps (InDesign, Word...) do not display *San Francisco* as an option in their font menus.

Here's another example, from Apple's very own Keynote (whose default font is still Helvetica) - no San Francisco there either:

[image]

Obviously, this font is there, somewhere in the system, since it's used almost everywhere! And Apple computers are sold with lots of fonts pre-installed in their System Folder, so it seems like a mistake to me, that this one in particular would be unavailable.

So, how could I "unlock" it, or make it usable in other applications?

NOTE: *This question was first assuming - wrongly - that San Francisco was made available in Yosemite, which was a mistake. Turns out I still can't find and use it in El Capitan, so I just edited it to say "El Capitan" instead, and add a few images, but some comments might seem irrelevant.*

Comment: If you have a paid Apple Developer Account then from [Introducing San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) click on San Francisco Fonts under Download Fonts and accept the License Agreement...

Comment: San Franciscos is coming with the new OS X version, El Capitan. It's not on Yosemite yet.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was looking at it but it's a different font sized Helvetica that is now being used in Yosemite I guess...

Comment: Can't vote to close as this question has an open bounty - but imo it's a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/is-there-a-user-font-for-san-francisco-in-el-capitan

Comment: Which is from october 3rd while mine was posted on sep 19, @Tetsujin imo it's the other one who's a dupe ;)

Comment: hehe - fair point, though it was still referring to Yosemite until November, long after the other had an answer ;-)

Comment: I understand, good point too, although the answer was true also when the question was about Yosemite, since the font is NOT accessible within El Capitan, but through another source :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download it from here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

But there is this note in the license agreement:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: THE APPLE SAN FRANCISCO FONT IS TO BE USED SOLELY FOR CREATING MOCK-UPS OF USER INTERFACES TO BE USED IN SOFTWARE PRODUCTS RUNNING ON APPLE’S iOS OR OS X OPERATING SYSTEMS, AS APPLICABLE.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! You helped me avoid using it for a professional print project. A "modern" take on type but a rather old approach to copyrights...

Comment: link doesn't work w/o dev subscription

Comment: @BretFisher: The link above, and the font download links that appear on that page, all seem to work now (Aug 2021) without a login required. =)