# How can I switch Chrome to display web pages with the San Francisco font in El Capitan?

Tags: google-chrome, font, text, macos

I'd like for Chrome's default sans-serif font for websites to be San Francisco. However it's not showing up in the font list. Any ideas for how to change this setting?

[image: Chrome font settings dialog]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the San Francisco font to be user-accessible. (See [Can I use or access the San Francisco font that comes with El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206431/12285)) Once you do this, you will be able to set it as the default font in Chrome.

Comment: Is this still the case? For SF Mono you can just get it from Terminal.app