# Is there a user font for San Francisco?

Tags: keynote, font, macos

I thought the new Apple font was called *San Francisco*, but I cannot find it in the font list of the Keynote.app for my Mac. Is it called another way or it is not available for Keynote?

I am currently using OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are System fonts & not available (or indeed licensed) for documents that you make or App use in general.
As mentioned in comments, even the [developer version](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) of the fonts is only licensed for interface mockups & no other purpose.

The previous system font, Helvetica Neue, on the other hand, was released as both a System & User font.

There are various opinions online about how to make the San Fransisco fonts available to the user, but seem to depend on unpacking the individual ttfs, changing the 'system font' attribute, then repacking them again - something I'll leave to someone else, regardless of the licensing or legal position of doing that.

Comment: The fonts are available via the [Developer site](http://developer.apple.com) for registered developers, but the license only allows its use to create mockups of interfaces and prohibits other uses.

Comment: @AlanShutko - yes, I was aware of that - but they are not available for non-developers [except by some rather dubious routes] so I though I should leave that out of a 'user-level' question.

Comment: I think there's not really the need to change any attribute. There are copies available from which can just install directly. But yeah licensing-wise that might be dubious.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, just convert all the SFNS*.otf font in /System/Library/Fonts/ to ttf and install them to ~/Library/Fonts/. That will work fine.

EDIT : Apparently, it's working only for Pages, Keynote and Numbers under the name "System Font". Can't get it to work on other programs.