# Can't find or use San Francisco in apps like Sketch

Tags: font, facebook

I understand that the font is only available for developers, but i'm not one at the moment, but when trying to use facebook sketch template for ios9 i get a prompt saying this

[image]

My question is if there is a way a round this without messing with the system default fonts as this repo does https://github.com/supermarin/YosemiteSanFranciscoFont or is it the only way?

system: macbook running osx el-capitan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short [& even long] answer is no.

It's not only that it's only available to developers, it's that it is not licensed for use as a user font at all, in any way, shape or form.
Even developers are only licensed to use it for screen mockups etc.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208854/85275

Even if you unpack it, tweak it so it no longer appears as a system font & repack it, it would then be a different font & the substitution would happen anyway,

Comment: that's what i'm afraid of but whats really bothering me is that i'm not interested in using the font, i just want to use the ios9 templates for sketch, so is there another way (besides purchasing a developer membership) to be able to use sf font with mockups on elcapitan?

Comment: That translates as "How can I be licensed to use this without purchasing a license?" The answer is along the same lines...

Comment: fair enough, one last question, do you think the https://github.com/supermarin/YosemiteSanFranciscoFont would work well on el capitan?

Comment: It's a System Font - it will replace Yosemite's system font, not make it available in your user fonts.

Answer (score 12):

Initially, you had to have a developer account. Now anyone can download the font at https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ and install them on your system (using the font book app).

Now Sketch is satisfied and it won't give you any warnings about the missing San Francisco font.

Comment: Note that it doesn't seem to force you to log in as a developer at the above link. I was able to download without logging into my account first.

Comment: But I still don't see the font in font book

Answer (score 2):

This guy is a hero - you can download the font here:
http://www.developertown.com/apple-tvos-sketch-template

Or direct download:
http://cl.ly/1N1k3i1L361h/download/SF-Fonts-August-26.zip