# How do I set the mail.app message font to San Fransisco (System Font)

Tags: mail.app, font

I'm using Mail.app in Mac OS X 10.11 (Yosemite).

I would like for messages I compose to appear in the new, lovely, San Francisco font. I cannot seem to make that happen because neither "System Font" or "San Francisco" are available in the OS X Font chooser.

Is there a way to make this font available for message composition?

Comment: @Tetsujin I think the answer is the same (thanks, btw!) but the question is different enough that most people won't find that other question if they're looking for this.

Comment: Having it linked as a dupe is actually better for Googlers in future - they have twice as many chances to find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to solve this problem that you *definitely should not pursue* because it may be a licence violation:

- Download the SF fonts from [developer.apple.com/fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)
- Open the downloaded fonts in Font Book.
- Boom.

Thanks to [tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) for this answer to a [similar, more general](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208854/7244) question