# How do I choose "System Font" in the font picker?

Tags: macos, mail.app, big-sur, font

I have migrated from an old iMac running Catalina to a new one running Big Sur.

I assume, deep in the annals of time, I must have changed my default font in Mail for the Message List to be slightly bigger. It is set to Lucida Grande 12.

On the new iMac, this choice seems jarring in Big Sur.

On another iMac, migrated from a laptop where I had not changed the default font size, Mail shows my Message List font as System Font Regular 11.

When I go to change the font back to default, the font picker does not show any font called System Font, and I do not know what the actual system font is in Big Sur - is it Helvetica Nueue, San Francisco, or something else?

*Ideally, how do I get rid of my custom font choice and revert to the default?*

I am aware there are two similar questions here

- [Is there a user font for San Francisco in El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/is-there-a-user-font-for-san-francisco-in-el-capitan)
- [How do I set the mail.app message font to San Fransisco (System Font)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218540/how-do-i-set-the-mail-app-message-font-to-san-fransisco-system-font)

Neither of them answer my particular question.

Comment: I have *exactly* this same question.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem odd, but you *can't* find the "System Font" in the Font Picker. However, you *can* restore the default "System Font" setting for the message list (and then, if you like, use the Font Picker to adjust only its font *size*). Here's how.

[*NOTE: I've tested this method successfully in the **"Big Sur"** and **"Catalina"** versions of **macOS**.*]

---

### Easy way: the "defaults" command

Quit **Mail.app** if it's running, and then open **Terminal** and execute the following command:

```
defaults delete -app Mail MessageListFont
```

The next time you launch **Mail**, you'll find the message-list font has reverted to the system default. Enjoy!

---

### A less elegant alternative, if needed

If for whatever reason the technique described above doesn't work — and you're desperate — you can try this "brute force" method instead.

Quit **Mail.app** if it's running, and then open the following file in a text editor (such as [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)):

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist
```

(To be extra-safe, make a backup of the original `.plist` file before editing it.)

Once open, find the "MessageListFont" key/value pair. It will look like this:

```
    <key>MessageListFont</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGBwpYJHZlcnNpb25ZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3BYJG9iamVjdHMS
    AAGGoF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEICVRyb290gAGkCwwVFlUkbnVsbNQNDg8QERIT
    FFZOU1NpemVYTlNmRmxhZ3NWTlNOYW1lViRjbGFzcyNAKgAAAAAAABAQgAKAA1hUaG9u
    YnVyadIXGBkaWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNWTlNGb250ohkbWE5TT2JqZWN0CBEa
    JCkyN0lMUVNYXmdud36FjpCSlJ2irba9wAAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAAABwAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAADJ
    </data>
```

Delete the entire key/value pair, and then re-save the file. (If it seems you're not able to do this directly, try using "Save as…" to save the edited version "on top of" the original version, replacing it.)

The next time you launch **Mail**, you should find that the message-list font has reverted to the system default. Congrats!

Comment: I tried to accomplish the desired result using the `defaults delete com.apple.mail MessageListFont` command in Terminal, but for some reason the system claimed it couldn't find the "com.apple.mail" domain. Trying with "com.apple.mail-shared" didn't work, either. So… "brute force" to the rescue!

Comment: Because it's a Sandboxed app, use `defaults delete -app Mail MessageListFont`.

Comment: @benwiggy That version didn't work for me, either, in Big Sur. I also tried supplying the full pathname to the plist file itself… still no workie. Even with a `sudo` boost. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @benwiggy Update: I tried the "-app" style again, and this time it worked. I'll update my answer, leaving the "brute force" method as a just-in-case alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Editing completed. Thanks again, @benwiggy.

Comment: In my experience, you will get the "Domain com.apple.mail does not exist" error if Terminal does not have "Full Disk Access". Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access and make sure Terminal.app is checked.

Comment: Excellent point, @MarieFischer. I normally apply "Full Disk Access" to Terminal as a standard practice, but at the time when the `defaults` command didn't work for me, I probably was logged into a temporary account that I hadn't set up that way. Thanks for catching that oversight!