# May use the San Francisco font for my web apps?

Tags: font

I've found that new SF UI font for download (http://nomail.com.ua/font/SF%20UI%20Display). I wonder if it's legal to use it in the web app I am building now, i.e. for commercial use? I haven't found any licence info on the official page (https://developer.apple.com/fonts/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/is-there-a-user-font-for-san-francisco-in-el-capitan) generally answers the question of legality.

Including these font files in your app and using them with `@font-face` or `@import` is unquestionably not permitted.

However, for a web app you can non-explicitly use it by [specifying special keywords](https://webkit.org/blog/3709/using-the-system-font-in-web-content/) [in your CSS](http://furbo.org/2015/07/09/i-left-my-system-fonts-in-san-francisco/):

```
body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Helvetica Neue",
      "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI";
}
```

This will, of course, result in slightly different appearances per platform and version (namely non-Apple platforms and Apple systems before iOS 9/OS X 10.11).

Comment: Nowadays, `system` should probably be replaced with `system-ui`.  See: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#system-ui and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5640395337760768

Comment: @DemPilafian That is true, please propose an edit to the answer.