# How to use System Font in macOS apps?

Tags: font

I'm trying to replicate some text I found on a webpage.  Chrome dev tools identifies the font as `.SF NS` but I can't find this in Font Book, nor can I find it in any other app such as Text Edit.  I tried looking for names like "SF", "San Francisco", and "System".

I did find the font file at `/System/Library/Fonts/SFNS.ttf`.  But when I try to open this in Font Book, nothing happens.  The Finder *Get Info* dialog shows that the full name is "System Font".  How can I use this font to type text in any app?

I'm running Ventura 13.5.2.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a user font for San Francisco?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/is-there-a-user-font-for-san-francisco-in-el-capitan)